# Ruby Install on CentOS

Tags: centos, openssl, ruby

I’m trying to install Ruby on Centos-6.4 64-bit as following:

```
mkdir /tmp/ruby && cd /tmp/ruby
curl --progress ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz | tar xz
cd ruby-2.0.0-p247
./configure --disable-install-rdoc
make
sudo make install
```

During the `make`, following error is displayed:

```
ossl_pkey_ec.c: In function ‘ossl_ec_group_initialize’:
ossl_pkey_ec.c:766: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘EC_GF2m_simple_method’
ossl_pkey_ec.c:766: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
ossl_pkey_ec.c:821: error: ‘EC_GROUP_new_curve_GF2m’ undeclared (first use in this function)
ossl_pkey_ec.c:821: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
ossl_pkey_ec.c:821: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[2]: *** [ossl_pkey_ec.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ext/openssl'
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-p247'
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

I have already installed it on CentOS 6.5 without this issue, I need it now on CentOS 6.4 & the issue is seems to be related to OpenSSL.

Comment: Mind me asking why you can't just use `rvm` to install the latest build for you?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are hitting a bug in Ruby’s OpenSSL API which is in p247 and earlier versions. While the links I give are Fedora specific, I think same issue will be for CentOS.

Try applying [this patch](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/41808/diff?format=diff) before building. More info [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8384).

Answer (score 2):

You most likely need the system library & related headers from `openssl-devel`. Try this:

```
yum install openssl-devel
```

And if you somehow want to cover all dependencies, this should work:

```
yum install patch gcc-c++ make bzip2 autoconf automake libtool bison iconv-devel readline readline-devel zlib zlib-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel
```

Then just go back into your `ruby-2.0.0-p247` directory, do a `make clean` & try again from square one.

A lot more details on “gotchas” for installing Ruby on different systems [can be found here](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/wiki#make-error-for-200-p247-and-lower-on-fedorared-hat).

Comment: confirm the fix. Works on latest ruby 2.3 as well. No patch required.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `openssl-devel` is installed. 90% of the problems during compilation is a missing dev packages.

Comment: openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4.x86_64
openssl-devel-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4.x86_64

Already Installed

Comment: How can you have openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4.x86_64 installed on a CentOS 6.4 machine? That is a CentOS 6.5 package IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mentioning, that after installing any dependencies, you need to rerun the configure step. Simply rerunning make won't do, at least not in all cases.